# Wordpress nginx rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am trying to do following rewrite rule on my wordpress page.
I have a page `www.mydomain.com/videa` and I want to configure it in the way, when someone types `www.mydomain.com/videa/some-string` it will be rewrited (not redirected) to `www.mydomain.com/videa/?v=some-string` but the user will still see his URL `www.mydomain.com/videa/some-string`.

We are running Nginx server, i tried following rule `rewrite "^/videa/(.+)$" "/videa/?v=$1";` but it keeps saying page not found.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in this case you are trying to add extra variables to an existing WordPress page, so something like this should work:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^videa/(.+)/?', 'index.php?v=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

You can put that into your themes `functions.php` or create a plugin it. You'll need to flush you rewrite rules by re-saving permalinks in the WordPress admin interface.

Comment: will this work with nginx? since nginx ignores .htaccess

Comment: Yes. Your nginx config file should have something similar to this: `location $uri $uri/ index.php$is_args$args`

Comment: it does something, but it returns me to my homepage, not to /videa page.. can you help with that?

Comment: What is /videa? Is it a page or a post or a custom post?

Comment: a single wordpress page, not a post

Comment: I changed your rule to `add_rewrite_rule('^videa/(.+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=7&v=$matches[1]', 'top');` and after that it redirected me to a page /videa where in $_GET i found an index 'q' with my required slug. I don't know why 'q' and not 'v', but however it works good. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it!

Answer (score 0):

Try "re-saving" the Permalinks settings  from the dashboard after you do the change (/wp-admin/options-permalink.php). Sometimes it fixes the issue.